# Java/Android: How do I randomly generate 12 objects from an array of 20 objects onto a GridView using an Adapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am new to Android development. I am currently working on an app and would like to generate 12 images randomly onto a grid using an Adapter class. I currently am able to generate a random number of images from the array onto a grid... but the number of images changes each time e.g. 2 images, then 16 images, 8 images, etc.

I have declared a global Random variable and have been using it within the getCount() method.

`ImageAdapter.java`

```
public imageAdapter(Context context, Image[] images) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return **random.nextInt(images.length);**
}
```

Hopefully, this is enough information. It's my first question I've asked on Stack.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: according to your code, what you generating random is `number of images` to show in grid. If you want to keep number of images same but randomize the image order, this code won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that this code won't work. I have asked the question on stack so someone can shed insight into how I can get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried looking for generating random number with range. I guess what you can do is have a small range and everytime generate random number from that range only, so that it won't vary drastically.

Comment: Hi @ShadowDroid. Thanks for your reply. I managed to work it out. 

        List<Image> imageList = Arrays.asList(images);
            Collections.shuffle(imageList);
            Image[] shuffled = imageList.toArray(images);

        List<Image> list = Arrays.asList(shuffled);
            shuffled = Arrays.copyOfRange(shuffled, 0, 12);
            return shuffled.length;
    }

This seemed to work perfectly :-)

Comment: Great. From your code It seems you want to shuffle the dataset as well. Initially from question I thought you want keep same set in same order just reduce or increase data size. Anyway good that you were able to come up with solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can randomize the order of the images in the list by following approach:

`Collections.shuffle(images);`

While `shuffle()` takes a `Collection` as input, you'll have to convert your `Array` to `List` which you can do by following:

`List<Image> imageList =  Arrays.asList(images);`

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-or-randomize-a-list-in-java/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for again for your reply. Although your reply did not give me the direct answer, it indirectly led me a resource that worked. Big thank you :-) 

https://www.journaldev.com/32661/shuffle-array-java

Comment: oh, okay let me make this answer specific then. I thought you'll be able to convert the array to list. give me a minute.

Comment: I am glad I could help you. I'll appreciate it if You accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I'm new to stack, I received this message.
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."